# mouse over event within certain window y range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project that requires the full length logo shrink to short initial in 2 situations:
A) when page scroll down past 300px.
and 
B) if page hasn't scroll past 300px (meaning full length logo still showing), shrink the full length logo to initial to accommodate pulldown menu when mouse over the top menu items.

Here is the code I tried:
it is working but when page scroll past 300px the mouse out should not happen. It should keep the logo as the smaller initial format. Right now the mouse out will happen no matter the page is scroll past 300px or not.

```js
/* shrink logo when page scroll past 300px by adding .smaller class to #logo. */

window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 300 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 300) {
        document.getElementById("logo").className = "smaller";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("logo").className = "";
    }
} 

/* shrink logo when mouse over top menu items (.showlp) only if page has NOT scroll past 300px */

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".showlp").mouseover(function(){
  if (document.body.scrollTop < 300 || document.documentElement.scrollTop < 300) {
         document.getElementById("logo").className = "smaller";
   }
     })
  $(".showlp").mouseout(function(){
   if (document.body.scrollTop < 300 || document.documentElement.scrollTop < 300) {
         document.getElementById("logo").className = "";
   }
     })
 
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Pass parameters via data attribute in the body tag and access that value via you javascript code.
Eg.

then on your javascript

```
  var ctrl=
  $("body").attr("
  data-var");
```

then on your window scroll function set the attribute value to 1, aand listen to it on your mouse over function to know when to 
add the functionality.
Eg.
       Function 
       myfunction(){
       if(document.bo
       dy.scrollTop>3
       00){
      // swap urclass
     // then do
      $("body").attr("
     data-var", 1);
      }

then on your mouse over function do:

```
   $(document).re
   ady(function(){
 $(".showIp").mo
  usover(functio
  n(){
  var ctrl=
  $("body").attr("
  data-var");
  if(ctrl==1){
  //swap class
  }
 else{
 //keep swap
  }
  });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried adding your code to my test page and it's still not working. Sorry I don't know much about javascript so it's probably on my part that I can't make your code work.

Comment: Do you know html that much?

Comment: <body data-
       var="0">
then you can use javascript to change the value of data-var attribute and listen to it with ur action event

Comment: I still can't make it work. Instead of introducing a new element, is it possible to use check if the class ".smaller" exist for #logo? And apply mouse over event only when #logo does NOT has .smaller?
I tried this but still don't work.

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".showlp").mousover(function(){
  if ($("#logo").not(".smaller")) {
     document.getElementById("logo").className = "smaller";   
  }else {
         document.getElementById("logo").className = "";
     }
  })
});

Comment: I fixed my old code and it's working to some extent now, even though it still has some bug like mouseout event shouldn't work when page scroll past 300px.